# batch file not working for registry edit

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to disable popup blocker using above script. This is not working and registry value is still 1 only after execution.

```
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\New Windows" /v "PopupMgr" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

Comment: This script is only to add the key not edit the actual value?

Comment: @SCramphorn, the `/f` option tells to overwrite the current value...

Answer (score 1):

There should be no reason why that data cannot be changed, are you sure you are altering and checking the key for the currently active user?
I have tested the below script sucessfully, it toggles the pop-up blocker on or off depending upon it's current state.

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SET "KEY=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\New Windows"
FOR /F "SKIP=2TOKENS=3" %%A In ('REG QUERY "%KEY%" /V PopupMgr') DO SET "_=%%A"
IF %_% EQU 0 (SET/A _+=1) ELSE SET "_=0"
REG ADD "%KEY%" /V PopupMgr /T REG_DWORD /D %_% /F>NUL
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this article [Windows Central](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-edit-registry-using-command-prompt-windows-10) it may help you with what you want.

If you cannot edit it, why don't you just delete the key and re-add it by using `REG Delete`